# Gem not found when trying to run post-install for dev container

Tags: ruby, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, ubuntu-19.04

I've set up a non-root user and have run into these errors when it get's to this point of building my dev container. If I remove the root user it runs fine. These steps are listed in the post install.

Below are the errors I receive in the terminals.

```
Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c gem install bundler -v 1.17.3 && bundle install && rake db:create && rake db:migrate && rake assets:precompile && rake db:seed
```

```
Start: Run in container: /bin/sh -c gem install bundler -v 1.17.3 && bundle install && rake db:create && rake db:migrate && rake assets:precompile && rake db:seed
/bin/sh: 1: gem: not found
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:19.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# TODO: it would be nice to use the vscode user instead.
#  until then we silence the warning.
ENV BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING = true

# fix sources
RUN sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN sed -i 's/security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/' /etc/apt/sources.list

# TRICKY: this has to be installed first
RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get install -y build-essential ssh-client

# add older repository so we can get libssl1.0-dev
RUN echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list

# Add non-root user.
ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1001
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    #
    # [Optional] Add sudo support. Omit if you don't need to install software after connecting.
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME

# update packages
RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        tzdata git vim iputils-ping apt-utils procps ca-certificates gnupg2 curl wget && \
    apt-get clean

# install RVM
RUN gpg2 --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D39DC0E3 39499BDB
RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# Add user to RVM.
RUN usermod -a -G rvm $USERNAME

# Set the default user. 
USER $USERNAME

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-l", "-c"]
RUN echo 'source /etc/profile' >> ~/.bashrc

# install ruby
RUN rvm install 2.3.8

# install bundler
RUN gem install bundler -v 1.17.3

# install application dependencies
# TRICKY: these must be installed last
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs=10.15.2~dfsg-1 libcups2-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmagickwand-dev mysql-client redis-server
```

Comment: `rvm` is...invasive and complicated.  Since a Docker container only runs one application, you don't usually need a version manager like `rvm`.  Can you use the Docker Hub `ruby:2.3.8` image without these customizations (NB, it will not get current security updates)?  Or, more directly install that specific version of Ruby you need without using a version manager?

Comment: @DavidMaze its a screwed up repo I'm working with so trying to keep it as close as I can to it's current setup. As far as I know there aren't any other good ways to run 2.3 on ubuntu 19.04

Comment: This sounds like a `PATH` issue caused by RVM not loading properly. You might be able to fix it by manually figuring out where RVM put the Ruby binaries, and then adding that folder to your `PATH`. RVM breaks very easily if it is not loaded properly or if anything in your Bash rc files mucks with `PATH`. Please log into the docker container and find out where RVM put Ruby, and verify RVM is working properly on the command prompt.

Comment: Also you are installing RVM as root but logging in as another user. I would recommend you do a single-user install instead. So many ways you can break RVM. It is probably easier to troubleshoot it as a single-user install. Therefore do not install as root, but as the user that is actually going to run Ruby in the end.